# execute f:setPropertyActionListener when click on button after onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

in one page I have a datatable that contains all users, each line contains two additional columns "edit" and "delete",  the problem is on the botton delete
when the user click on "delete" button I show him a confirmation dialog with component primefaces and if he clickon "ok" I run a method that delete user from database
but the problem is in the button :

```
 <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton   actionListener="#{utilisateursController.supprimerUser()}" value="Supprimer" onclick="confirmation.show()" type="button" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener id="jesusi" value="#{car}" target="#{utilisateursController.u1}" />  
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
```

to delete the user it must be affected to `utilisateursController.u1`
but when I click in this button the code below

```
 <f:setPropertyActionListener id="jesusi" value="#{car}" target="#{utilisateursController.u1}" />
```

doesn't be executed

then, the `utilisateursController.u1`  remains null

do you have any idea
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't execute because you added `type="button"`. Remove that part. Also, you should be opening the dialog with `oncomplete` instead of `onclick`, so that by the time the dialog is opened, the selected row is already in `utilisateursController.u1`. That way you can include attributes (like name) in the confirmation dialog (you'll have to update dialog from button if you want to do this).

Comment: thank you Damian, now it works, but the user doesn't disappear from the datatable, if I want it disappears I must to refresh the page manually,
do you have any idea thank you

Comment: here is the code of the method of managedBean public String supprUser(){
       uh.deleteUtilisateur(u1) ; 
       return "utilisateurs";
   }, with utilisateurs is the xhtml page

Comment: from the button in the dialog that executes the delete method, you have to update the table